# How to find all symbolic link in PWD which refer to files outside of PWD? unix

Tags: shell, unix, hyperlink, pwd

i can find all link in dir by command:

```
find . -type l
```

But i need link which only refer to files outside of PWD.
Can anybody say how to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: with readlink i get error; solaris 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
find . -type l -exec readlink -f '{}' \; | grep -v "^`readlink -f ${PWD}`"
```

`readlink -f` gives you the canonical path of a file, so the first command gives you the path of links and the `grep` command excludes files beginning with the current path.

If you want to remember which links pointed to those paths, here's a way to do it:

```
find . -type l -exec sh -c 'echo $(readlink -f "{}") "<-- {}"' \; \
  | grep -v "^$(readlink -f ${PWD})"
```

the `-exec` switch is more complicated since you have to display both the linked path and the path of the symlink.

Comment: @Dshell maybe `readlink` is not installed on your system... Which OS are you using? On my Debian box, `readlink` comes with the coreutils package.

Comment: If you don't have readlink, you can cook up your own in two-line perl script, or you can use `ls -L` tied together with `sed` and `awk` to extract the symbolic link path.

Answer (score 1):

Ich would do something like:

```
for link in `find . -type l`; do X=$(dirname `readlink $link`); if [ $X != '.' ]; then echo $link; fi ; done
```

Comment: Compile readlink yourself: ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/patches/2.2/common/readlink.c